# Trying to power 100 Arduinos from single power line

Tags: arduino, power, buck, rs485

I'm trying to power up to 100 Arduinos that will be spread across a 25m wall using a single power line.

The idea is each Arduino will have a few a few buttons, leds & an oled screen and will all communicate to a master server using rs485.

```
====[A0]====[A1]====[A2]====[A3]====[A4]== ... ==[A99]
```

I've already followed this brilliant post http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428 to implement the data connection using an rs485 bus.

However I'm struggling to understand how I could power multiple Arduinos from the one line without affecting the quality of the data bus.

Would I be able to use a 48v power rail with buck converter for each Arduino?

Would I have to isolate each Arduino and rs485 driver (my concern is the length of the wire will create different ground potential and effect the quality of the data bus)?

Comment: The same question on Arduino Stack Exchange: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/55579

Answer (score 3):

If your arduino is doing little more than reading buttons and comnmuniction on the RS485 bus I wouldn't worry too much about the power. At 10mA per Arduino the total consumption would be ~ 1A. Feeding at both ends would half the load. You could even feed in a couple of places in the middle.

Using buck converters would greatly reduce the currents (and the bills), so that would be a good idea if the current would be too high.

RS485 is a safe choice, but do you really need it? I think I would go for a daisy chain, where each Arduino (-nano) sends (UART output) to the next (UART input), modifying the message by insterting its own button data. With 25/100 = 0.25m between adajcent Arduino's this should be pretty reliable.

A nice extra is that the ground potential is only an issue between two adjacent Arduino's.

(I once designed such a system, which did include enumeration and bootloading. IIRC the final configuration used 30 chains of 100 nodes each.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How did your system handle dead nodes in the chain? Would it still be feasible to do this with rs485?

Comment: No specific handling of dead nodes. Why wouid a node be (or become) dead? - RS485 can be used for point-to-point, why not, but it would be a bit overkill IMO.

Comment: You overlooked the OLED displays.  Those will substantially increase power consumption.

Comment: _"Using buck converters would greatly reduce the currents (and the bills) ..."_ - How would buck converters reduce the bills? You still need the same amount of power. (Also, in my experience, a non-sleeping Arduino is more like 25-30mA than 10, but that's still very manageable)

Comment: Keep your GND voltage drop to about 0.1 volt; that is well within the noise margin of digital protocols. Do the same for VDD. And have a capacitor right across the GND/VDD pins of each board, so the surge currents are supplied RIGHT THERE.

Comment: @chris I indeed overlooked the OLEDs.

Comment: @marcelm the OP suggested n 48V rail with buck converters, which reduces power compared to anything that uses a higher-voltage rail with linear regulators.